# pyspark : conditionally transform columns based on multiple columns

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, pyspark, data-transform

I have a dataframe where the ID column is represented in different ways and different character lengths and I am trying to make it uniform . How can i do this with multiple conditions ? I tried the following, but didn't work

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace, lpad
from pyspark.sql.functions import when
df= df.withColumn('new_ID', 
    when(df.ID.startswith('TEST'),regexp_replace(df.ID,'TEST','')))
```

below is a sample dataframe

```
|ID|
----
TEST-001-005|
09-023|
001456|
```

The expected dataframe is as below

```
ID|
---
001-005|
009-023|
001-456|
```

Comment: For the first condition I think you forgot the `-`: `df.ID,'TEST-','')`. You can also use with `.otherwise(...)` when conditions are not met.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do what you're asking:

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

# create a sample dataframe with the 'ID' column
data = {'ID': ['TEST-001-005', '09-023', '001456']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# define the regular expression
regex = r'\b([A-Z]*-)?(\d{1,3})-(\d{3})\b|\b(\d{3})(\d{2,3})\b'

# define the replacement function
def replace_id(match):
    if match.group(1):
        return f"{match.group(2).zfill(3)}-{match.group(3).zfill(3)}"
    elif match.group(4) and match.group(5):
        return f"{match.group(4).zfill(3)}-{match.group(5).zfill(3)}"
    else:
        split_id = match.group(0).split('-')
        split_id = map(lambda x: x.zfill(3), split_id)
        return '-'.join(split_id)

# apply the regular expression and replacement function to the 'ID' column
df['ID'] = df['ID'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(regex, replace_id, x))

# print the resulting dataframe
print(df)
```

This assumes the format of your dataframe, some modifications would likely need to be made if it's different.